# Android MediaMuxer illegalstateexception failed to stop the muxer mMediaMuxer.stop()

Tags: android, mp4, fatal-error, android-mediacodec, muxer

I am having problems stopping the MediaMuxer.

Pretty much have followed [fadden's example](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt) all the way, except I am using audio, so I am not 100% sure the audio and video tracks line up yet. This might be the problem.

When I hit the breakpoint for mMediaMuxer.stop() I get a fatal error:

```
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304): FATAL EXCEPTION: CaptureManager
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to stop the muxer
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at android.media.MediaMuxer.nativeStop(Native Method)
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at android.media.MediaMuxer.stop(MediaMuxer.java:190)
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.MyMediaMux.stop(MyMediaMux.java:97)
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.CaptureManager.stopMuxer(CaptureManager.java:86)
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.MyMediaCodec.stop(MyMediaCodec.java:209)
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.MyMediaCodec.checkEOS(MyMediaCodec.java:190)
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.MyMediaCodec.runQue(MyMediaCodec.java:177)
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.MyMediaCodec.runQue(MyMediaCodec.java:182)
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.MyMediaCodec.sendEOS(MyMediaCodec.java:199)
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.CaptureManager$2.run(CaptureManager.java:94)
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-30 17:11:21.677: E/AndroidRuntime(32304):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I can step into it far enough to tell MediaMuxer.mState = MUXER_STATE_INITIALIZED when I call stop. But it is failing in the nativeStart(mNativeObject) ...

```
if (mState == MUXER_STATE_INITIALIZED) {
    nativeStart(mNativeObject);
    mState = MUXER_STATE_STARTED;
```

Comment: Are there other messages in logcat preceding the exception?  Error messages, status updates ("Video track stopped"), ...?

Comment: Yes, there were, I am a bit away from this now, I kind of gave up the approach of copying info to the surface through a Parcel or canvas. I am following your 2nd example as best I can to get to work with my stuff. I believe this had to do with the muxer not being set up correctly, but I really couldn't say. I would think the muxer should be able to package the data as an mp4 even if the data is scrambled garbage. But I wasn't able to get the files it was creating to play. VLC was thru this errors "mp4 error: MP4 plugin discarded (no moov,foov,moof box)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the exact same exception and for me the problem was, that I forgot to start the whole testcase in a thread.

Comment: Yes, I've had a lot a problems bouncing back and forth between threads with this example. It seems there are things that need to happen on UI and other things that need to be off loaded. I should have a strong example posted shortly [here](https://github.com/hpp/penelopefree/blob/master/src/com/harmonicprocesses/penelopefree/camera/Pcamera.java) but I haven't pushed in awhile and I am kinda buried right now.